# React make part of prop bold inside a component

Tags: reactjs, components

Is there a way to make part of a prob that contains strings bold? 
I've tried the array method but I've heard its not the correct way to do it

```
<ListItemText primary={thread.data.title} secondary={"Author: " + thread.data.author} />
```

I would like the "Author: " to be bold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In react props could be anything: functions, string, objects and...JSX
Try:

```js
<ListItemText 
  primary={thread.data.title} 
  secondary={<span><b>Author</b>{thread.data.author}</span>} />
```